# With the code that I have, how can I redirect a new User to a page when they finish registering?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am building an app with Flutter, Firebase and Android Studio. Although not new to Android Studio, I am a begginer with the first two and am currently following these [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA3NWDBPZ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=1) .

I was able to build the User authentication just fine and wanted to start building away from the tutorial.

Right now, after Registering or Signing In, the user is redirected to the same Home page.
What I want is when a user registers their account, they are redirected to Screen#2 and when a user signs in, they are redirected to Screen#1.

I am using a StreamProvider that listens for authentication changes and passes that information. The wrapper decides the screen the user is redirected to.

I cant seem to make the "click" to solve this basic issue.

Thank you in advance.

**auth.dart**

```
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
  }

  Future registerWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(email);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
} catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**wrapper.dart**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null){
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you registered and singed in, I guess the program always take you directly home page. And I think you should singout to access the register page again.

Comment: It does exactly that the way it is built. But my question is how would I make it so when a user registers their account they are sent to Screen2 while users that login are sent to Screen 1.

Comment: it is up to the user's uid. if a uid is registered, it takes user homepage, but if another uid is not registered, it takes user registerpage. I also watched your firebase series, I think you should follow him.